Evaluating $\int_0^\infty \frac{J_0(k\rho) \sin(kt)}{k^2 + \lambda^2} \, \mathrm{d}k$ when $t>\rho$
Consider the following improper integral, which arose while solving a fluid mechanics problem:
$$
I = \int_0^\infty \frac{J_0(k\rho) \sin(kt)}{k^2 + \lambda^2} \, \mathrm{d}k\, ,
$$
where $\rho, t \in [0, 1]$ and $\lambda > 0$.
I attempted to evaluate this integral analytically using the method of residues by integrating the function of complex variable $z$
$$
f(z) = \frac{H_0^{(1)}(z\rho) \sin(zt)}{z^2 + \lambda^2}
$$
over a closed contour composed of the upper side of the branch cut from $-R$ to $-\epsilon$, a small clockwise-oriented semicircle of radius $\epsilon$ centered at the origin, the positive real axis from $\epsilon$ to $R$, and a counterclockwise path along the upper half of the circle $|z| = R$.
What I find is
$$
I = i\pi \, \text{Res}\{ f(z), z = i\lambda \} \, ,
$$
which is obtained as
$$
I = \frac{i\pi}{2\lambda} \, H_0^{(1)}(i\lambda\rho) \sinh (\lambda t)\, .
$$
I can confirm using numerical methods that this result holds when $t \leq \rho$. However, when $t > \rho$, it seems that additional terms need to be considered. I have checked that the integrals over both the small and large circles should vanish, though I may be mistaken.
Any thoughts? Any hints of help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

The integral over the large semicircle doesn't vanish when $t>p$.

@RandomVariable Thanks. So from there an additional contribution emerges. I will have a look at this.
